# Changing url and path to object level Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have one polymorphic model which has attachment. For example:

Image : Polymorphic model
  Product and Customer are two different model which uses Image as polymorphic

Image model has attachment called :file which has :path and :url.
  I don't want to share :url and :path for Product and customer.

I need different url and path for Product and Customer model (i.e) I want to differentiate 
  url and path based on object type.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you want to not share? Do you want to save the file to another location for customers? or another url?

Comment: I want to save customer and product images in different location. for ex: customer imgs in /runtime/shared/customer_images, products images in /runtime/shared/public/products_images. And url for both should be different ex: customer url- customer/:id/:file_name, product url- product/:file_name

Answer (score 1):

If you need different Images on Product and Customer, why do you use a polymorphic relationship (I assume?) in the first place? If a ProductImage and a CustomerImage have nothing to do with each other (as you need to differentiate url and path?!) then why not simply make them two entirely independent Models? (Or, maybe, if that fits, inheriting from some shared base)